# Google Maps Api v3 custom InfoWindow - "google is not defined" error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

trying to create custom infowindows in my application that is based on google maps.

next example is one of my base points for development:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html

problem is that whatever i use this or some other example, in forefox's firebug i'm getting error

```
google is not defined
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

can you help me how to solve this, i can not continue my work without custom infowindows.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

my mistake - i did not include properly google map api library - i included infobox.js before http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false